# Unity3D Collision in Multiplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, game-engine

I'm creating a rocket league like game.
My problem is the ball.
I wrote a scipt who sets up the ball position and rigidbody based on syncvars which the server sets each 0.01 second.
This works well.
The hosting player can touch the ball and it does move on the client aswell.
My code works.
But the problem appears when I'm trying to touch the ball with a client.
The player object glitches into the ball and physics doesn't really work.
The ball gets moved sometimes but it's stil weird movement.
I guess the problem is that the ball doesn't really get the rigidbody changes from the client.

This is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Ball_Behaviour : NetworkBehaviour {

    [SyncVar]
    public Vector3 syncedballpos;
    public Vector3 ballpos;
    [SyncVar]
    public Quaternion syncedballrot;
    public Quaternion ballrot;

    public AudioClip boom;

    [SyncVar]
    public Vector3 syncedballrigvel;
    public Vector3 rigvel;
    [SyncVar]
    public Quaternion syncedballrigrot;
    public Quaternion rigrot;

    public GameObject ball;
    public Rigidbody rig;
    public AudioSource aud;
    public GameObject pat;

    public float offset;
    // Use this for initialization
    override
    public float GetNetworkSendInterval()
    {
        return 0.015f;
    }

    void Start () {
        aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        GetNetworkSendInterval();
        ball = this.gameObject;
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        offset = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            setball();
        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(rigvel, syncedballrigvel) > offset)
        {
            rig.velocity=Vector3.Lerp(rigvel, syncedballrigvel, 1f)*Time.deltaTime*0.05f;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(ballpos, syncedballpos) > offset)
            {
                this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(ballpos, syncedballpos, 1f) * Time.deltaTime * 0.05f;
            }
            /* if (Quaternion.Angle(rigrot,syncedballrigrot)>1f)
             {
                 rig.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rigrot,syncedballrigrot,0.7f);

             }
             if (Quaternion.Angle(ballrot, syncedballrot) > 1f)
             {
                 this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(ballrot, syncedballrot, 0.7f);

             }
             */
        }
    }

    [ServerCallback]
    void setball()
    {
        syncedballrigvel = rig.velocity;
        syncedballrigrot = rig.rotation;

        syncedballpos = this.transform.position;
        syncedballrot = this.transform.rotation;
        // RpcDoOnClient(syncedballpos);
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        aud.Play();
    }

    public void scored()
    {
        this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;

        Instantiate(pat, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);

        aud.PlayOneShot(boom,2);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a LateUpdate for the ball position? Also, have you checked your script execution order to verify that this is getting called prior to the player ? And lastly, I assume that your collision detection is continuous ?

Comment: My detection is continuous. But the problem is the script, yeah. I changed it now. The ball got updated like always. And that's the problem. Imagine you're kicking the ball as a client. The server detects the collision, but since it's updating positions nearly all time it resets the ball to its position. And since float numbers are always a little different the ball gets ported back a few millimeters. But that's enough to produce weird behaviour. I am now trying to only update if the ball on a clients game is like 1 Meyer away from the servers. So that the collision happens server side.

Comment: Maybe you could try interpolating the velocity of the ball so that it doesn't require being continuously set via the server? I understand your problem though, I think that collision detection on the server would definitely solve this issue, but not ideal if you are planning on having many games running concurrently.

Comment: Yes.That's what I thought first ,too. But handling collision on the server is quite difficult in this case because the cars who kick the ball can reach more than 300 mph. And I guess that is way too fast to predict. But I didn't try to interpolate the ball because I don't really know how it works as I never had to use it. What I'm trying now is handle collsion on client and Lerp the ball if clients ball Vector3.Distance(clientball,serverball)>1. But if this is true the ball changes position to 0,0,0 on the client. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Because the speeds are so high, you should probably ray trace ahead of the car in that direction by the distance the car will be traveling during that frame. That should allow you to work out if there will be a collision. Also, sounds like your current efforts are very similar to client side interpolation. You would give the client ball a velocity and position, and let the client side ball physics do its thing, then say 30 frames later, hard update these values from the server again. A classic example of this is in MMO's where when people lag they start teleporting,.. that's the interpolation.

Comment: Okey. Thank you! I will try that out. But if I lerp the positions it's not lagging that much,right? And this game is only a school projekt I have to do so it doesn't need to work under higher ping environments. LAN is completely enough. Do you think it would still lag in a lan network ?

Comment: I think on LAN it won't be noticeable at all. I think that because it is a school project, just off put the majority of your calculations to the server because it will save a heap of time w/ your networking code.

Comment: Okey. Another thing. It kind of "works" right now. Or at least it does something useful. Everytime the distance reaches the limit, the ball gets telported to 0,0,0. But at least the script detects the difference. But I can't really figure out why this is happening. I'm gonna update my Question to the new script. Take a look if you don't mind.

Comment: is ballPos null? I can't see where you are setting it to a value.

Comment: I just put it on the scene. It has a value n startup. But anyway it resets to 0,0,0..

Comment: Now the collision works, but on the client side it's still kinda different. The server player can roll the ball without problems whereas the client player is struggling with the ball rolling over them.

Comment: Your LERP implementation is incorrect which is probably why its going to the wrong location, 1f should be the "percentage" (in decimal form) between start and end point. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html Pretty hard for me to suggest how to fix your current issue though.

Comment: Yea, I know. But that's why I set it to 1f. It should be the synced position where the ball lerps too..

Comment: ballPos should be the position that is getting streamed in, and then the target position should be the projected ball position, then you LERP towards the projected position and once it is reached then you check the server and get an updated position. Note: Vector3.Lerp(ballpos, syncedballpos, 1f) == syncedballpos;

Comment: That sound like an idea. I'm going to test it today. I'll come bacl here later to tell you about my result. Thank you very much

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to the problem? I am stuck with something very similar.

Comment: @MohsinAli Actually, yes. Not the way I wanted to do this but it worked.
No need to asnwer this question here, because the UNet Version I used back then is highly outdated. But you can contact me here for a chat about what I did.

Comment: @MarcelKulina I would really like to know what you did. My player prefab is a simple sphere with a Rigidbody (of mass 0.5), a NetworkIdentity set to LocalPlayerAuthority, a Sphere Collider and a NetworkTransform. The NetworkTransform is set to sync RigidBody 3D. Collisions between the players are always glitchy no matter what values I set for the NetworkTransform. At this point I am considering writing my own SyncTransform script.

Comment: Actually, what you could do is transmit the impact a player causes to the server and have a local rigidbody on each local end. This would only broadcast touches on the ball to each player. If the position of the ball differs from the server data, lerp to that pos.